# "Bar m" needs love in Firefox 4.

Tags: bug, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox 4: MathML vs MathJaX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/firefox-4-mathml-vs-mathjax)

"Bar m" i.e. $\bar{m}$ looks fine in Firefox 3.6, but is still broken in the release version of Firefox 4.0

Comment: are you asking another variant of this? http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/firefox-4-mathml-vs-mathjax

Comment: @Jeff - sorry, I guess I am, although that seems to be a more general complaint.